# How does the Many-Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Physics relate to Consciousness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, perception

According to the Many-Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, each quantum event causes the world to "branch" into a superposition of outcomes.

How come "my" consciousness only chooses one of these outcomes? How is this choice made? And for all the branches I don't experience, are those NEW consciousnesses being born, or are those consciousnesses that somehow already existed alongside mine previous to the measurement?

Also, wouldn't this mean that the conscious minds of people in our lives are constantly branching off into new, different realities? Or is any conscious mind in any branch somehow as "old" and "contiguous" as any other, rather than being "new?"

Comment: You should probably provide the definitions of "consciousness" and "choice" that you're using (and presumably want us to use).

Comment: note that your consciousness doesn't necessarily "choose" one of the outcomes, but each branch of consciousness is only aware of itself

Comment: @lurscher so are all the consciousnesses in every branch as "old" and "contiguous" as any other? Or are some just created at the split?

Comment: @BruceGreetham could you elaborate? What part of my proposition do you agree with?

Comment: @BruceGreetham if I could ask you another question, do you think that consciousnesses in every branch are as "old" and "contiguous" as any other? Or are some just created at the split?

Comment: Re, "How come "my" consciousness only chooses one of these outcomes?" If many worlds was true, then your consciousness would not choose. It would fork, and go both ways. There would be an astronomical number of other _yous_ asking variations on this question and, an astronomical number of other yous who have not thought to ask this question,...

Comment: Re, "...consciousness...old...contiguous...new..." What you're asking here is philosophical---Not something that physics can answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow if I could ask you to elaborate in any case, do you think each branch is therefore as "old" and "contiguous" as any other? The problem I'm struggling with is that according to my experience, there is a consistent "I" which only experiences one branch. Are the branches I don't experience created as "new" consciousnesses at the split, or are they somehow contiguous with my consciousness before the split, even though afterwards they are different from the experience that "I" observe?

Comment: One of the big problems with not defining "consciousness" and "choice," as I suggested you do, is that it turns the rest of the discussion into complete nonsense. Why are we assuming that whatever "consciousnesses" are, are remotely related to whatever "choice" means? There are definitions of "choice" that are not even remotely related to the human brain, let alone consciousness (for example, what if "choice" is the outcome of a probabilistic interaction between an electron and a positron?).

Comment: yes, consciousness branches every time, but the evolution of the wavefunction is unitary so the universe does not really split, it is just something subjective

Comment: I object to this question being on hold. Sometimes physics will intersect with other fields. Plenty of physics is required in order to properly answer this reasonable question. (Like building in intuition for why some might believe in the MWI).  It sounds more like some people particularly don't like this interpretation and want to snuff out any discussion of it. But sometimes (take Einstein for example) thought experiments to work out incompatibilities are sometimes very fruitful - even if they don't involve a perfectly defined mathematical problem.

Comment: @JakeZhou  - I do not believe your question is "philosophical" in the sense that people are dismissing it as rhetoric. Many posters insist that it is just an issue of language which universe "you" are in. But obviously existing in two universes simultaneously is very different than one (and you could imagine it would feel different 'empirically')!  Some dismiss your question as being a matter of 'subjectivity' - but those who insist that "subjective truths" have nothing to do with physics should review special relativity.

Comment: @BruceGreetham  You are of course entitled to your own opinion, but the question was put on hold not because it is a "bad question" but because it's "opinion based".  Ironically, the "better" question you provided actually asks for a resolution to differences in /opinion/ between academics. And if you don't believe me, you can see in the comments that after the question didn't get responses for some time - the asker states "Seriously, noone has a opinion either way?"

Comment: My opinion is that this is a good question, because I believe that there are answers to this question that are not primarily opinion based.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, this problem with uncertainty and duality=((... I was in you shoes for a long time until I finally read a decent modern interpretation. Something like the following: the act of measurement causes collapse (not breeding) of possibilities into one realization out of the whole pool of possible outcomes. Before the experiment all those possibilities are statistically possible.

A non-ideal analogy: imagine you study a gas of identical particles. You can measure pressure, temperature, volume... All of those are statistical parameters, not deterministic. Sure, they depend on the momenta, masses etc of each and every particle in that gas, but you, in your experiment, don't have access to that information. More than that, each independent measurement of the local velocity of some random particle is meaningless and useless. Similar thing is happening in quantum. You can only talk probabilities, the outcome of each independent event is ill-defined. In quantum statistics you can even introduce quantum ensembles, where this thermodynamic analogy becomes completely legit.

The only other thing to discuss is how Heisenberg uncertainty contributes here, but it is a separate topic. I personally prefer to blame locality...

This interpretation doesn't have the highlighted philosophical conflict with physical reality we observe. (To clarify, in this interpretation asking the question above is nonsense because many-world interpretation is not necessary.)

Copenhagen interpretation is OLD, as most of its derivatives at that time, imho. It was developed at the point when a lot of representatives of general scientific community were not comfortable with probabilistic description. General public is still cranky about this... But scientists had to somehow explain physical phenomena on publicly available level, and they did it in the best way they could at that point...

P.S.: I fully accept criticism in advance as I know that this way of thinking about that is fairly unusual.

Comment: -1 Your answer doesn't address the question, which is about the Many-Worlds Interpretation, not your personal interpretation.

Comment: @D. Halsey No it does, paragraph #3 =)

Comment: "The only other thing to discuss is how Heisenberg uncertainty contributes here, but it is a separate topic. I personally prefer to blame locality..." ???

Comment: @Bruce Greetham yes, indeed interesting. I guess I read the question as coming from a student, possibly, early graduate. At that level stuffing this philosophy is evil... This is for curious, not for beginners. But I get your point.